# Is there a way to insert html tags with css?

Tags: html, css

I know it is not a good practice, but when somebody bans  tags in html you have to find a solution.
So, is there a way to include in html via css the

```
<script>
```

tag? Maybe with :after and content:"" ?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible with CSS. With JS, yes.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. The `content`-like properties all interpret literal characters only. (Probably for exactly this reason - were it possible, it would be a security nightmare)

Comment: "I know it is not a good practice, but when somebody bans tags in html you have to find a solution. " - Uhm, no.

Comment: No, when someone bans HTML tags you have to live with it and not try to bypass their restrictions.

Comment: It's possible in old IE browsers with `expression()` fwiw. What a horrible idea and like @Pekka웃 said a security nightmare. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that. CSS is for styling, your best bet is Javascript.